# libtool: link: warning: .../libstdc++.la seems to be moved

Tags: libtool

I've been getting a lot of warnings of this form (line-break added for readability):

```
libtool: link: warning: `/usr/local/gcc-5.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/
    5.2.0/../../../../lib64/libstdc++.la' seems to be moved
```

and couldn't figure out why or if the warning is relevant. Note that both paths resolve to the same location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the custom installation of gcc-5.2.0 installed a libstdc++.la with the following `libdir` line:

```
libdir='/usr/local/gcc-5.2.0/lib/../lib64'
```

But when libtool links against `libstdc++.la`, it uses the path reported in the warning (which also happens to be part of `g++ --print-search-dirs` output—this is likely related).

The fix is to change the `libdir` value in `libstdc++.la` to the exact path that `libstdc++.la` is searched in by libtool:

```
libdir='/usr/local/gcc-5.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../../lib64'
```

Apparently, libtool won't normalize or canonicalize paths and compares them as strings, thus the error. See also [a related thread on the libtool mailing list from 2006](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-libtool/2006-04/msg00012.html).